# Where can I store a mapping method?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I work on an app with Sinatra framework. I would know where the best place is to store a mapping method: in a controller or a decorator. In fact, I import data from a French website that has a French territory, and I want to convert the number territory from number to name.

Here is my method:

```
def territory_mapping(code)
  {
    '01' => 'Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes',
    '02' => 'Hauts-de-France',
    '03' => 'Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes'
  }[code]
end
```

I want to know where I can store this method.

Comment: This depends on the context and complexity. Can you include code as an example?

Comment: I've added example.

Comment: Try and declare fixed hashes like that as constants so you don't need to create new objects (and garbage!) each time that method is executed. That's just a look-up table. If your Sinatra app is just one file you can put that anywhere you like. If it has multiple files it's up to you as to where it goes, Sinatra has no specific conventions like Rails does.

Comment: How are you going to know the place?

Comment: Do you need this hash only in one controller/one class for your business logic? If so, just put the hash as a constant inside that file

Comment: I need this method for 2 class. I've two mapping method like that. And there is about 100 departments from France so it's 2 big methods with ~ 200 lines. I just want to keep my code clean.

Comment: I'd put the mapping in a configuration file, probably JSON or YAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```rb
begin
  case "my hash's use" do
    when "it's for display" then
      if "it's a small method"
        "put it in a helper for use a controller"
      else
        "put it in a module and include it using via `helper`"
      end
    when "it's not for display" then "put it in a helper for use in a route block"
  else
    "it should go in the class that requires it."
  end

rescue NoMethodError => e
  e.message = <<~MESSAGE
    If it doesn't work because the logic isn't defined
    in your views or route blocks then it should go in 
    the class that requires it."
  MESSAGE
ensure
  "I get out more so I stop answering this question in Ruby ;-)"
end
```

In other words, put it in a helper and then you can assess later whether it should go somewhere else.

Regardless, @tadman is right about declaring that example hash as a constant, you should treat access to that as you would to any other constant - if you need it in more than one place then have it the level above in the namespace hierarchy. If it's a lot of data then @Stefan is right to say to load it from somewhere else.

Comment: It also amuses me that the branching could be tighter :-D